# How to fix the Errno 13 permissionError?

Tags: python

I want to read the contents of a txt file created by another program. To do this I just use this line:

```
with open("Input.txt", "r") as file:
        content = file.read()
```

My problem is the following:
My code runs in an infinite loop and searches for this specific file. If the file is already here when my program gets started it works perfectly fine, but when its running and the "Input.txt" file gets copied to the directory of my program, then it throws this error:

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'Input.txt'

Doeas anybody have an idea why this happens and how to prevent this?

I use python3.7.3 on windows 10 (64bit)

Comment: can you show `copy process` in your code ?

Comment: You're probably constantly checking if the file exists and trying to open the file as soon as it does. If something else is writing the file into your project folder, the file will be there right away, but it may be locked for some time (since it is being written). Your program would have been fine if it had waited for the write to complete and then opened it. A solution could be to catch the `PermissionError` and ignore it, then just try again - but a more efficient solution would be to listen for new files using something like the watchdog library https://pypi.org/project/watchdog/

Comment: @Grismar I changed it to wait a second if it finds the file and read the content afterwards. Now it works!! Thank you very much